# Unable to reset JavaScript bar graph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bar graph created in JavaScript to display values using colors. I am having trouble resetting the bar graph. Basically what needs to happen is when the "reset" button is clicked, all bars clear values and reset to "0".  Then the button needs to give the option to "Generate" and the previous values are shown again. Also, this is my first time using constant velocity to ease the bars up and down as the button is clicked to give it a little flair. Not sure what I am missing to have the data clear and be set to zero on the bottom line of the graph while using constant velocity to make it ease down and when button is clicked to restore the values to previous state.  Any help is appreciated. Here is the code so far:

***HTML***

```js
/*
 * Some base values.
 */

var millisecondsPerFrame = 30;

/*
 * Helper function for managing button event handlers.
 */
var setupButton = function(button, label, onclickHandler) {
  button.value = label;
  button.onclick = onclickHandler;
  button.disabled = false;
};

var startConstantVelocityAnimation = function() {
  // Grab the desired velocity.
  var velocity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("chart").value);

  // Grab the object to animate, and initialize if necessary.
  var colors = document.getElementById("colors");
  chart.style.bottom = chart.style.bottom || "0px";

  // Start animating.
  var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    var newBottom = parseInt(box.style.bottom) + velocity;
    if ((newBottom < 0) || (newBottom > maxBottom)) {
      velocity = -velocity;
    } else {
      chart.style.bottom = newBottom + "px";
    }
  }, millisecondsPerFrame);

  // Toggle the start button to stop animation.
  setupButton(document.getElementById("Reset"), "Reset", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);

    // Toggle the start button to stop animation.
    setupButton(document.getElementById("Reset"),
      "Generate", startConstantVelocityAnimation);
  });
};


window.onload = function() {
  // Set up the initial event handlers.
  document.getElementById("Reset").onclick = startConstantVelocityAnimation;
};

**
* Graph JS Code ** *

  function createBarChart(data) {
    // Start with the container.
    var chart = document.createElement("div");

    // The container must have position: relative.
    chart.style.position = "relative";

    // The chart's height is the value of its largest
    // data item plus a little margin.
    var height = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      height = Math.max(height, data[i].value);
    }
    chart.style.height = (height + 10) + "px";

    // Give the chart a bottom border.
    chart.style.borderBottomStyle = "solid";
    chart.style.borderBottomWidth = "1px";

    // Iterate through the data.
    var barPosition = 0;

    // We have a preset bar width for the purposes of this
    // example.  A full-blown chart module would make this
    // customizable.
    var barWidth = 48.30;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      // Basic column setup.
      var dataItem = data[i];
      var bar = document.createElement("div");
      bar.style.position = "absolute";
      bar.style.left = barPosition + "px";
      bar.style.width = barWidth + "px";
      bar.style.backgroundColor = dataItem.color;
      bar.style.height = dataItem.value + "px";
      bar.style.borderStyle = "ridge";
      bar.style.borderColor = dataItem.color;

      // Visual flair with CSS Level 3 (for maximum compatibility
      // we set multiple possible properties to the same value).
      // Hardcoded values here just for illustration; a
      // full module would allow major customizability.
      bar.style.MozBoxShadow = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.75) 0px 7px 12px";
      bar.style.WebkitBoxShadow = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.75) 0px 7px 12px";
      bar.style.boxShadow = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.75) 0px 7px 12px";
      bar.style.MozBorderRadiusTopleft = "8px";
      bar.style.WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius = "8px";
      bar.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "8px";
      bar.style.MozBorderRadiusTopright = "8px";
      bar.style.WebkitBorderTopRightRadius = "8px";
      bar.style.borderTopRightRadius = "8px";
      bar.style.backgroundImage =
        "-moz-linear-gradient(" + dataItem.color + ", black)";
      bar.style.backgroundImage =
        "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%," +
        "color-stop(0, " + dataItem.color + "), color-stop(1, black))";
      bar.style.backgroundImage =
        "linear-gradient(" + dataItem.color + ", black)";

      // Recall that positioning properties are treated *relative*
      // to the corresponding sides of the containing element.
      bar.style.bottom = "-1px";
      chart.appendChild(bar);

      // Move to the next bar.  We provide an entire bar's
      // width as space between columns.
      barPosition += (barWidth * 2);
    }

    return chart;
  };

window.onload = function() {
  var colors = [{
      color: "red",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      color: "blue",
      value: 10
    },
    {
      color: "green",
      value: 100
    },
    {
      color: "black",
      value: 65
    },
    {
      color: "yellow",
      value: 75
    },
    {
      color: "purple",
      value: 120
    },
    {
      color: "grey",
      value: 121
    },
    {
      color: "orange",
      value: 175
    },
    {
      color: "olive",
      value: 220
    },
    {
      color: "maroon",
      value: 275
    },
    {
      color: "brown",
      value: 300
    },
    {
      color: "teal",
      value: 15
    }
  ];

  var chart = createBarChart(colors);
  document.querySelector("#wrapper").appendChild(chart); // keeps chart inside wrapper div
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 85%;
  border: groove;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
}

#loginwrap {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* topnav links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change color on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* three columns next to each other */

.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Card-like background for each section */

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* Align about section image to right */

.aboutimg {
  float: right;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.copyright {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}


/*Chart Color Legend*/

.legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.legend .legend-scale ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%;
  list-style: none;
}

.legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 15px;
  width: 50px;
}

.legend a {
  color: #777;
}

.subs {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.reset-button {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tissue: Titan Issue Tracking</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Issue Tracking System" />
  <meta name="author" content="S Morris">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tissue.css">
  <script src="js/animation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h2>TISSUE: Sales Subscription Dashboard</h2>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="Login.html">Tracker Login</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="legend">
        <div class="legend-scale">
          <div class="reset-button">
            <input type="button" value="Reset Graph" id="Reset">
          </div>
          <ul class="legend-labels">
            <li><span></span>40</li>
            <li><span></span>10</li>
            <li><span></span>100</li>
            <li><span></span>65</li>
            <li><span></span>75</li>
            <li><span></span>120</li>
            <li><span></span>121</li>
            <li><span></span>175</li>
            <li><span></span>220</li>
            <li><span></span>275</li>
            <li><span></span>300</li>
            <li><span></span>15</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="legend">
        <div class="legend-scale">
          <ul class="legend-labels">
            <li><span style='background:red;'></span>Jan</li>
            <li><span style='background:blue;'></span>Feb</li>
            <li><span style='background:green;'></span>March</li>
            <li><span style='background:black;'></span>Apr</li>
            <li><span style='background:yellow;'></span>May</li>
            <li><span style='background:purple;'></span>June</li>
            <li><span style='background:grey;'></span>July</li>
            <li><span style='background:orange;'></span>Aug</li>
            <li><span style='background:olive;'></span>Sept</li>
            <li><span style='background:maroon;'></span>Oct</li>
            <li><span style='background:brown;'></span>Nov</li>
            <li><span style='background:teal;'></span>Dec</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <hr>
      <div class="subs">***Subscribers in Thousands***</div>
      <script src="js/subscriptions_graph.js"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    Copyright &copy; 2018 Titan Issue Tracker
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the item with id 'cv-velocity' ?

Comment: What is 'box' that you are using in startConstantVelocityAnimation function? Wher are you declaring it?

Comment: sorry...this is my first time trying constant velocity...I was trying to make the box be the chart

Comment: You need to update your code so that someone can suggest you anything on your problem.

Comment: **Edit** changed box to chart and cv-velocity is now colors which is what I'm trying to have called so they can be reset and generated. I also added the script for the graph. Thank you for looking into this.